# Download fails, is it wrong with the keep-alive?

Tags: download, http-headers, keep-alive

Downloading a file directly (without any scripts) from the server, sometimes it fails for slow internet connections.
e,g for any file, each time users can download some percent of the file. And sometimes they can download it completely.
In the cases that download fails, browser doesn't show a "Failed" text. it seems the file has been downloaded completely.
I thought it might be with the keep-alive connection. I use these response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=172800
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:36195412
Content-Type:application/x-rar-compressed
Date:Tue, 28 Jul 2015 07:00:49 GMT
ETag:"a9825a8-2284c54-518bca9ddaaad"
Expires:Thu, 30 Jul 2015 07:00:49 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5
Last-Modified:Wed, 17 Jun 2015 20:37:46 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.12
Vary:User-Agent
```

And one more question.You can see in the headers that keep-alive is set like this: `keep-alive:timeout=5` there is no `max` here. so is it default to 0 or something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out that it is not related to `keep-alive`. I and most of our clients were using proxies, it made some problems.